# Is it possible to get the stacktrace of an error in the error_logger handler?

Tags: erlang, stack-trace

im currently writing an error_logger handler and would like to get the stacktrace where the error happend (more precisely: at the place, where `error_logger:error*` was called). But I cannot use the `erlang:get_stacktrace()` method, since i'm in a different process.

Does anyone know a way to get a stacktrace here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not fully debugged it, but I suppose that the error functions simply send a message (fire and forget) to the error logger process, so at the time your handler is called after the message has been received, the sender might be doing something completely different. The message sent might contain the backtrace, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: No, it doesn't contain it. It believe, there is no way to get that info, too. Just asking to get sure. :(

Answer (score 3):

get_stacktrace() returns "stack back-trace of the last exception". Throw and catch an exception inside error_logger:error() and then you can get the stacktrace.

```
error() ->
  try throw(a) of
    _ -> a
  catch
    _:_ -> io:format("track is ~p~n", erlang:get_stacktrace())
  end.
```

Comment: Some problems with this approach: a) There might not be a real exception, just a call to error() b) I cannot modify the `error()` function, since its part of the stdlib c) I'm in a different process, so I cannot call `get_stacktrace()`

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the question.